# Variable in grep regex

Tags: regex, bash, grep

```
#! /bin/bash
NAME='joe'
FILE="joewhatever@gmail.com\nwhatever@joe.com\nwhateverjoe@gmail.com"
echo -e "$FILE" | grep "${NAME}*@"
```

I'm getting:

```
whateverjoe@gmail.com
```

And I expect to get:

```
joewhatever@gmail.com
whateverjoe@gmail.com
```

And let out:

```
whatever@joe.com
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In regular expressions, `*` is a quantifier that means zero or more repetitions of the preceding pattern. After variable substitution, your regexp is `joe*@`. This matches `jo` followed by zero or more `e` followed by `@`. `joewhatever@gmail.com` doesn't match that pattern, since it has `whatever` between `joe` and `@`.

You want `joe.*@` as the regexp -- `.` matches any character, so `.*` means to match any number of them. So it should be `"${NAME}.*@"`

```
echo -e "$FILE" | grep "${NAME}.*@"
```

Answer (score 4):

A dot `.` is absent before the star `*`

```
#!/bin/bash
NAME='joe'
FILE="joewhatever@gmail.com\nwhatever@joe.com\nwhateverjoe@gmail.com"
echo -e "$FILE" | grep "${NAME}.*@"
```

> joewhatever@gmail.com 
>   whateverjoe@gmail.com